# Saving File to Folder using PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, fopen, tcpdf

Few examples I've tried

```
// Worked
fopen($OutputFolderPath."Text.pdf", "w");

// Didn't work
$pdf->Output($OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf','F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','F'

// Works with no PDF content inside
fopen($OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf','F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','w');

// Worked
$pdf->Output('C:/ISOSEC/PDFS/' . ReplaceWindowsFileNameSpecialCharacters($Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf'),'F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','F'
```

I'm trying to use the `$OutputFolderPath`

**'$OutputFolderPath' Path:**

```
//MIA-Test/htdocs/SharedFolder/MIA - Digital Post Natal Records/
```

**Error:**

```
fopen(file:////MIA-Test/htdocs/SharedFolder/MIA - Digital Post Natal Records/Fiona Appleton_1946546288 09_06_2015.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: use `file_put_contents()`

Comment: @PHPWorm... Can you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$a = file_get_contents('Text.pdf');
file_put_contents('new_text.pdf', $a);
```

Comment: i'm using $pdf->Output(); as i'm using tcpdf. I can't use file_put_contents. It's really weird because I can output it to a absolute path, but soon as I use a shared folder it doesn't work